# Side by Side bar plot not separating by the fill parameter

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have this side by side bar chart I want to make but instead of giving me side by side bars it only returns one of the two bars and I don't know why it makes it this way. If i exchange my x with the fill parameter it does side by side with the code I have.

```
library(ggplot2)

names(CF)

ggplot(data = CF, mapping = aes(x = País, y = Consumo, fill = Anos)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity')
```

MRE:

```
1995, LU - Luxemburgo, 7857.8
2019, LU - Luxemburgo, 20900.6
1995, GR - Grécia, 72162.3
2019, GR- Grécia, 0.0
1995, CH - Suíça, 148100.9
2019, CH - Suíça, 326411.2
```

This is what it's currently returning:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a reproducible and a bit more clear sample of your data set?

Answer (score 1):

By converting `fill` to a `factor` so it can be discrete rather than continuous and therefore you can `dodge` based on it.

You may try -

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = V2, y = V3, fill = factor(V1))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1995L, 2019L, 1995L, 2019L, 1995L, 2019L
), V2 = c(" LU - Luxemburgo", " LU - Luxemburgo", " GR - Grécia", 
" GR - Grécia", " CH - Suíça", " CH - Suíça"), V3 = c(7857.8, 
20900.6, 72162.3, 0, 148100.9, 326411.2)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained why this works

Comment: By converting `fill` to a`factor` so it can be discrete rather than continuous.

Comment: @DanAdams although this is kind of you, this information should be in the answer - otherwise the answer is not really useful.

Comment: @tjebo good point. Just submitted edit to the answer accordingly.